# Playstore not allowing app-bundle in production

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle, developer-console

I am trying to upload my app to playstore, but it is showing this error

```
The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) has reported version 16.0.0 as outdated. 
You must upgrade to a newer version (19.4.0+) before you can publish a new release to production.
Learn more about the SDKs that you're using and make informed SDK choices with Google Play SDK Index.
```

Thing is I don't have any `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` in my project, still it's showing this error, I tried updating my all my com.google.android.gms:play-services libraries but still the issue is same.

I also tried uploading the bundle to BETA, it was published successfully to BETA but when I tried to promote it to production, it gave the same error again.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You may have other dependencies that have play-services-ads as a dependency. You can run `./gradlew dependencies` to print a list of dependencies.